# Gradle and AndroidAnnotations

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-annotations

I have written a build.gradle file for my Android App. The App uses AndroidAnnotations.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

def AAVersion = '3.3.2'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.3.2'
    }
}

configurations {
    apt
}

apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName "de.xxx"
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/acra-4.3.0.jar')
}
```

The script does the APT profecessing and generates the Annotation_ classes. But afterwards the script fails with compilation of import-Statements and usages of classes like

```
import com.googlecode.androidannotations.annotations.AfterViews;
import com.googlecode.androidannotations.annotations.EFragment;
import com.googlecode.androidannotations.annotations.ViewById;
```

Whats wrong with the script? I know there is room for improvement.

Comment: [Looks like](https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/src/a72b4ae9be9667b7cac056c1f89b04f847ea7edd/src/main/groovy/com/neenbedankt/gradle/androidapt/AndroidAptPlugin.groovy?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#AndroidAptPlugin.groovy-20) applying android-apt plugin adds the `apt` config, you don't have to add it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this *build.gradle* :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

def AAVersion = '3.3.2'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}

apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0]?.processResources?.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName "de.xxx"
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/acra-4.3.0.jar')
}
```

The example script can be found in the [guide](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Building-Project-Gradle), or in the [sample project](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/blob/develop/examples/gradle/build.gradle).
Change the import statements like:

```
import org.androidannotations.annotations.AfterViews;
```

Comment: Many thanks. The package names of the androidannotations have changes since version 2.7.1 (I used this version under Eclipse).